# SQL Server express - Management studio installation hangs at native images installation

Tags: sql-server, installation, sql-server-2012, sql-server-express

I've been trying to install SQL server express edition (2014) with management studio and consistently failing to do so because installation stalls at step ***'Install_sql_common_core_Cpu64_Action : Write_NativeImage_64. Generating Native images'***. I've tried several time but still it hangs at this point. I even left it overnight but no progress.

I've even tried installing SQL Server 2012 management studio installation file but same issue again.

I tried to search for this kind of issue but no discussion found anywhere on internet. Any clue or pointers will be greatly appreciated. I've been trying since last couple of days but no luck.

Other details:

- OS: Windows 10 Pro
- Visual Studio 2015 Community edition installed
- All windows updates are up to date
- Downloaded management studio from MS site and File version is 12.0.2000.8

If any other details needed please let me know.

See below image:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disabling AVG virus protection before starting the install setup allowed me to proceed with the install past this point

Answer (score 0):

Try to  search for ngen.exe in task manager. After shutting down the process, installation runs smoothly. It might occur several times, so keep an eye if it`s not restarting.

Hope that helps :)